# Getting a list of all possible data type values in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types

If I have a data type say:

```
data Color = Red | Yellow | Green
```

Is there a way I can turn this into a list of type [Color] getting all possible values? [Red, Yellow, Green]

Perhaps this is a complete anti pattern?

Comment: I believe [toEnum 0 ..] works no matter how you change the data definition.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
data Color = Red
           | Yellow
           | Green
           deriving Enum

allColors = [Red ..]
```

Comment: This will break down when we add `| Pink`.

Comment: I believe `[toEnum 0 ..]` works no matter how you change the data definition.

Answer (score 64):

Not sure if it is an anti-pattern (nor can I think of a good use right now), but it's possible. Use the `Enum` (allows to generate a list like `[someCtor .. someOtherCtor]`) and `Bounded` (for `minBound` and `maxBound`) type classes. Luckily, you can derive both:

```
data Color = Red
           | Yellow
           | Green
           deriving (Enum, Bounded)

allColors = [(minBound :: Color) ..]
```

If you ever add another color, allColors get updated automatically. One restriction though: `Enum` requires all contructors to be nullary, i.e. adding `Foo Int` breaks the whole thing. Luckily, because a list of all possible values for this would be way too large.

Edit: The other answer works as well, maybe better since it doesn't require deriving `Bounded` and is therefore a bit shorter. I'll still leave mine because I love over-engineered but extremely generic code ;)

Answer (score 46):

Surely delnan's answer is better. Since I do not know how to include a piece of code in a comment, I'll give a generalisation as a separate answer here.

```
allValues :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
allValues = [minBound..]
```

Now, this works for any type with a `Bounded` and `Enum` instance! And `allColors` is just a special case:

```
allColors :: [Color]
allColors = allValues
```

In many cases, you won't even need to define `allColors` separately.

Comment: I agree with you, since Delnan's solutions doesn't require any reference to a real value from the type. On a SO note, perhaps I accepted too quickly, but the answer by adamse did work exactly as I asked.

Comment: +1 good point. (You can use backticks as usual in comments, linebreaks will be removed though - also, this wouldn't fit into a comment and you deserve rep for it anyway :) )

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of using this technique to parse enums with Parsec

```
data FavoriteColor = Maroon | Black | Green  | Red | 
                     Blue   | Pink  | Yellow | Orange
                             deriving (Show, Read, Enum, Bounded)
```

And the parsec parser

```
parseColor :: Parser FavoriteColor           
parseColor = fmap read . foldr1 (<|>) $ map (try . string . show) 
  [ minBound :: FavoriteColor ..]
```

of course the try could could be applied by better by pattern matching and a few other things could make it nicer but this is just an example of some usage of the technique.