# Haskell: custom data, using in function

Tags: haskell

I have created a data group:

```
data Cars = vw | audi | ford
data Engine = TDI | TSI
```

I want to use these in a function/list comprehension. To show combinations I have this:

```
[(x,y) | x <- Cars , y <- Engine]
```

But I'mm a little bit lost on how to use the `data` within a function.

I get this error:

```
Not in scope: data constructor `Cars'
```

Comment: Please also note, that names for type constructors and type names them selves both have to start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
$cat t.hs
data Cars = Vw | Audi | Ford 
        deriving (Enum, Show)
data Engine = TDI | TSI  
        deriving (Enum, Show)


main = print [(x,y) | x <- [Vw .. Ford] , y <- [TDI .. TSI]]


$ghc t.hs

$./a.out 
[(Vw,TDI),(Vw,TSI),(Audi,TDI),(Audi,TSI),(Ford,TDI),(Ford,TSI)]
```

Comment: You gonna splain what's going on here?

Answer (score 11):

`Cars` and `Engine` are types, nothing more, especially not lists of constructors. To get a collection of all constructors of a type, make it an instance of `Enum` and perhaps `Bounded` (you can `derive` both, `Bounded` is not necessary but nice as it allows not hardcoding the start value). See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299319/getting-a-list-of-all-possible-data-type-values-in-haskell) (in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299319/getting-a-list-of-all-possible-data-type-values-in-haskell/4300640#4300640)). Copying and adjusting that code (also, I fixed the casing of the ctors and renamed `Cars` as it was plural and not very specific):

```
data CarManufacturer = VW | Audi | Ford deriving (Bounded, Enum)
data Engine = TDI | TSI deriving (Bounded, Enum)

allValues :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
allValues = [minBound..]

allEngines = allValues :: [Engine]
allCars = allValues :: [CarManufacturer]

carsWithEngines = [(car, engine) | car <- allCars, engine <- allEngines]
```

Comment: I like this better than my approach; but it would be nice if you added the `deriving` clauses to your code.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of a generic `allValues` function, that never occurred to me. I know plenty of cases where this could save some code in my programs.

Comment: @Ferich: Even better, it's not a function but a friggin' *polymorphic constant*. Try beating that, average type system.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't access the constructors of a datatype this way.  First, all data constructors need to be capitalized, so change to this:

```
data Cars = VW | Audi | Ford deriving Show
data Engine = TDI | TSI      deriving Show

-- create explicit lists of the constructors
carTypes :: [Cars]
carTypes = [VW, Audi, Ford]

engineTypes :: [Engine]
engineTypes = [TDI, TSI]
```

now you can use these lists in a list comprehension

```
> let ll = [(x,y) | x <- carTypes, y <- engineTypes]
> show ll
> [(VW,TDI),(VW,TSI), (Audi,TDI),(Audi,TSI),(Ford,TDI),(Ford,TSI)]
> :type ll
> ll :: [(Cars,Engine)]
```