# Iterate over all (Row, Column) possibilities?

Tags: list, loops, haskell

This will be a TicTacToe implementation:

```
data Row    = A | B | C  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
data Column = X | Y | Z  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
type Pos = (Row, Column)
data Player = Player String
data Field = Field [(Pos, Player)]
initialField :: Field
initialField = Field []
```

As you can see, the initialField is just an empty list and as players make moves, (pos, player) tupels will get added to the list. So far so good. But now I have trouble writing a `possibleMoves :: Field -> [Pos]` function to get the empty fields. How do I iterate over all  Row, Column possibilities in Haskell? I get the feeling that my approach is wrong, but I'm new to Haskell so I have no better idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can get all positions with list comprehensions (see also the other answers)

```
positions :: [Pos]
positions = [(r,c) | r <- [A,B,C], c <- [X,Y,Z]]
```

and all plays with a map

```
occupied :: Field -> [Pos]
occupied (Field l) = fmap fst l
```

Then we can define possibleMoves (you will need to import Data.List to get `\\`, list difference):

```
possibleMoves :: Field -> [Pos]
possibleMoves f = positions \\ (occupied f)
```

A somewhat more compact version takes advantage of list comprehension constraints:

```
possibleMoves :: Field -> [Pos]
possibleMoves (Field l) = [(r,c) | r <- [A,B,C], c <- [X,Y,Z], (r,c) `notElem` occupied]
  where occupied = fmap fst l
```

Comment: Thanks, the last solution is very nice :).

Comment: There is even `\`notElem\`` that can be used to spare a pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

All rows (ref = [Getting a list of all possible data type values in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299319/getting-a-list-of-all-possible-data-type-values-in-haskell)):

```
Prelude> [(minBound :: Row) ..]
[A,B,C]
```

All columns:

```
Prelude> [(minBound :: Column) ..]
[X,Y,Z]
```

The compute the Cartesian product to find all possibilities (ref = [Cartesian product of 2 lists in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119730/cartesian-product)):

```
Prelude> [(x, y) | x <- [(minBound :: Row)..], y <- [(minBound :: Column)..]]
[(A,X),(A,Y),(A,Z),(B,X),(B,Y),(B,Z),(C,X),(C,Y),(C,Z)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an ultra short, "ulta-Haskelly" version:

```
enumAll :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
enumAll = [minBound..maxBound]

positions :: [Pos]
positions = (,) <$> enumAll <*> enumAll
```

(You'll also need to import Control.Applicative for the `<$>` and `<*>` operators)

Then in ghci:

```
*Main> positions
[(A,X),(A,Y),(A,Z),(B,X),(B,Y),(B,Z),(C,X),(C,Y),(C,Z)]
```

How the hell does this work?

`enumAll` is just a generic helper function (I was surprised not to be able to quickly find it in the standard libraries; it's possible I missed it and you don't even need to define it yourself). It gives you a list of every possibility for any bounded enumerable type. It's fairly straightforward; `Bounded` means the type has `minBound` and `maxBound`, `Enum` means you can use the `[a..b]` syntax to get a list of everything from `a` to `b`.

`(,)` is just the pair-building function. If you type `:t (,)` into ghci, it tells you `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)`.

Now, what about those weird `<$>` and `<*>` symbols? They're basically "special" forms of function application. So you can read it almost like we're simply applying `(,)` to the two arguments `enumAll` and `enumAll`. But because it's "special" application, it doesn't just give us the pair `(enumAll, enumAll)`.

What we're doing here is using the `Applicative` instance for lists. I'm not going to get into that in full detail, but what this does is help us think that `[Row]` is not a list of row values, but rather a single "unknown" row value. It's a value that *could* be any element of the list, but we don't know which one. The technical term usually used for this is that `[Row]` can be thought of as a *nondeterministic* `Row`; it's a `Row` value that could be a number of possibilities, but we haven't been able to determine which one it actually is.

So what we're doing is applying the function `(,)` (which just takes two arguments to build a pair), to two *nondeterminsitic* values, to get a nondeterminsitic pair (this is where we need the "special" version of function application with `<$>` and `<*>`; if we apply `(,)` normally with `(,) enumAll enumAll` or build the pair directly with `(enumAll, enumAll)` then all we get is a normal pair of nondeterminsitic values, instead of a nondeterministic pair of normal values - `([a], [b])` vs `[(a, b)]`) . And if I take a pair from all possibilities of one bounded enum and all possibilities of another bounded enum, then I should get all possibilities of pair! Which is exactly what happens.

The type signature `positions :: [Pos]` is actually necessary here. That's what tells Haskell we're building a list of `(Row, Column)` pairs rather than any other kind of pair of enums, which is how it knows that the first `enumAll` was enumerating all rows and the second wsa enumerating all columns. The most general type `(,) <$> enumAll <*> enumAll` is actually `(Enum a, Bounded a, Enum b, Bounded b) => [(a, b)]`, which will work just fine but is a pain to work with interactively in ghci because you'll keep getting ambiguous type variables whenever you try to print things.