# Idiomatic way of listing elements of a sum type in Idris

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I have a sum type representing arithmetic operators:

```
data Operator = Add | Substract | Multiply | Divide
```

and I'm trying to write a parser for it. For that, I would need an exhaustive list of all the operators.

In Haskell I would use `deriving (Enum, Bounded)` like suggested in the following StackOverflow question: [Getting a list of all possible data type values in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299319/getting-a-list-of-all-possible-data-type-values-in-haskell)

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be such a mechanism in Idris as suggested by [Issue #19](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/19). There is some ongoing work by David Christiansen on the question so hopefully the situation will improve in the future : [david-christiansen/derive-all-the-instances](https://github.com/david-christiansen/derive-all-the-instances)

Coming from Scala, I am used to listing the elements manually, so I pretty naturally came up with the following:

```
Operators : Vect 4 Operator
Operators = [Add, Substract, Multiply, Divide]
```

To make sure that `Operators` contains all the elements, I added the following proof:

```
total
opInOps : Elem op Operators
opInOps {op = Add} = Here
opInOps {op = Substract} = There Here
opInOps {op = Multiply} = There (There Here)
opInOps {op = Divide} = There (There (There Here))
```

so that if I add an element to `Operator` without adding it to `Operators`, the totality checker complains:

```
Parsers.opInOps is not total as there are missing cases
```

It does the job but it is a lot of boilerplate.
Did I miss something? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You can implement the `Enum` interface for `Operator` manually.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thanks, that's where I started really but I'm not quite sure how `fromNat` should behave for example.

Comment: That depends on your exact use case, but e.g. something like `fromNat Z = Add
  fromNat (S Z) = Subtract
  fromNat (S (S Z)) = Multiply
  fromNat (S (S (S _))) = Divide` might work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using `Enum` does seem more idiomatic but then I have to give up exhaustiveness which is a bit of a shame

Comment: you can still prove exhaustiveness, just prove that for every `op`, there is a `k : Nat`, such that `fromNat k = op`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option of using such feature of the language as [elaborator reflection](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/elaborator-reflection.html) to get the list of all constructors.

Here is a pretty dumb approach to solving this particular problem (I'm posting this because the documentation at the moment is very scarce):

```
%language ElabReflection

data Operator = Add | Subtract | Multiply | Divide

constrsOfOperator : Elab ()
constrsOfOperator = 
  do (MkDatatype _ _ _ constrs) <- lookupDatatypeExact `{Operator}
     loop $ map fst constrs

  where loop : List TTName -> Elab ()
        loop [] =
          do fill `([] : List Operator); solve
        loop (c :: cs) =
          do [x, xs] <- apply `(List.(::) : Operator -> List Operator -> List Operator) [False, False]
             solve
             focus x; fill (Var c); solve
             focus xs
             loop cs

allOperators : List Operator
allOperators = %runElab constrsOfOperator
```

A couple comments:

1. It seems that to solve this problem for any inductive datatype of a similar structure one would need to work through the [Elaborator Reflection: Extending Idris in Idris](http://davidchristiansen.dk/drafts/elab-reflection-draft.pdf) paper.
2. Maybe the [pruviloj](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/tree/master/libs/pruviloj) library has something that might make solving this problem for a more general case easier.